# Determine maximum number of threads that run on different windows systems

Tags: threadpool

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to find out the maximum number of threads that can run on different windows systems?

For example - (Assumption)A windows 32-bit system can run maximum 4000 threads.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a maximum number. Well, since we're using a finite amount of memory, it would be as many threads as you can fit into memory or as many as you can keep track of. Each system is different and I know Java and C don't have a function to provide this. C# can tell you how much memory a specific object/app needs so you could go calculate the estimate.

You could test this on your system. Write a sample app which spawns threads and see when you run out of memory. Use a counter to count them. This will give you roughly the range for your system.

In Java, you can use an `ExecutorService` with a thread pool.. Depending on which executor service you use, it can keep spawning threads if you submit more jobs.
A similar technique exists in C#.

A better question is what the **maximum number of threads to spawn and avoid thrashing** is.

Are you trying to take over the OS and do your own process/thread management? You should not be doing this.

Comment: If someone need so many threads they need to consider using a ThreadPool or reengineering the software.